# Laravel 5 dd and return statements showing different results

Tags: laravel

```
 public function getStoreData()
    {
        $page = $this->request->page ? $this->request->page : 1;
        $page_size = $this->request->page_size ? $this->request->page_size : 2;

        $storeData = Cache::get('single_store_response');

        return response()->json($storeData);
    }
```

When I  `dd($storeData)` I get accurate results when I make the api call, but when I return `response()->json($storeData)`, my result data brings something different.
How can I solve this issue and what's causing it?

OUT PUT EXAMPLE

> > dd($storeData) returns `['a','b','c']` which is a current data, but return response()->json($storeData) returns `['x','y','z']` which is an old data

Comment: _something different_ what's different?

Comment: doing a json serialization on a class will cause PHP to call the `jsonSerialize` method on the object if that implements [`JsonSerializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) or return basically nothing if it does not. From your question we don't know if `$storeData` is a class object or if it implements jsonSerializable (we don't really know anything about this variable really or even if this is what the issue may be) so  it would help if you actually shared these details

Comment: @Clement Baconnier - the data that's returned when dd is recent data, while the data that's return with the return statement is like a cached data of some sort, basically an old data

Comment: Are you storing something in the cache with the key `single_store_response` somewhere else? Reminder: The cache persist the data between requests AND between users.

Comment: @Clement Baconnier - I think it is, and i checked the `$storeData` type and it's returning an `array`

Comment: it's return data in the cache i think and not return the supposed data is should that's what is different @Clement Baconnier

Comment: Please show outputs as well

Comment: @Leena Patel i have updated the question with a description of what the out is like

Comment: try after running `php artisan cache:clear`